# Testing for a Google Drive wrapper library

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I recently wrote a library that wraps Google Drive API for Android. I would like to write some automated tests to make it more reliable and consistent during its evolution.

The library exhibits the same methods of the Google Drive API and returns the same objects. The only difference between this library and the APIs is the flow (in case you are asking why I did this).

For instance, I have a method `getMetadata(DriveId driveId)` that returns an object of class `Metadata`. This method is the wrapper for `getMetadata()` described and explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata).

Ignoring for a moment the fake authentication that I probably should provide in order to execute all the tests, in your opinion, what is the best way to test this kind of library?

What should be the goal of the tests?

Comment: How about mocking Google Drive API entirely?

Comment: @Anatoli ok. Mocking the Google Drive API is more like the 'how' of the tests. But the main question is: what should be the goal of the tests?

Comment: I was answering the "what is the best way to test this kind of library?" part :)
I guess the goal depends on the goals of your project.

Comment: Yes you are right. When you answered, I realized that my question was incomplete, so I updated it. The goal of my project is to correctly wrap the Drive API actions. So, I would make sure that if (for example) user want to create a new file on Drive through my library, this latter does its duty.